# Remove first value from multiple timeseries in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with some telemetry data for multiple devices. Every row has device ID and a timestamp and some other fields. I want to remove the first, that is earliest, entry for every device. How would I go about it?

For example, my data might look like this

```
timestamp,        device id, val1, val2, val3
2018-01-02 18:01  123        0     1     1
2018-01-02 18:05  124        1     3     2
2018-01-02 18:06  123        4     5     5
2018-01-02 18:02  125        2     7     2
2018-01-02 18:07  124        6     2     2
```

And I want to remove the earliest entry for device 123, earliest for device 124 and earliest for device 125 (even if it is the only one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use groupby and idxmax

```
df.loc[df.groupby('device id').timestamp.idxmin(), :]

    timestamp           device id   val1    val2    val3
0   2018-01-02 18:01:00 123         0       1       1
1   2018-01-02 18:05:00 124         1       3       2
3   2018-01-02 18:02:00 125         2       7       2

df.loc[df.index.difference(df.groupby('device id').timestamp.idxmin()), :]

    timestamp           device id   val1    val2    val3
2   2018-01-02 18:06:00 123         4       5       5
4   2018-01-02 18:07:00 124         6       2       2
```

Comment: I get an error that says `'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'timestamp'`. My dataframe definitely has the field, but I don't think it likes me trying to access fields in a groupby object.

Comment: Can you print df.columns? May be there is an empty string around it?

Comment: Looks like it was my fault, I dropped the timestamp column in one of my other notebook cells and forgot about it. Sorry. Let me see if this works for me.